# Why isn't my garage door opener button working on new installation?

Tags: repair, garage-door-opener, troubleshooting

I recently installed a garage door opener in my new home, it is wired as such per the installation instructions.

[image]

The garage was prewired with 20AWG, insulated and drywalled, and I identified which wires go where by testing continuity.  For the first couple days everything went swimmingly, then suddenly the button stops "working".  The opener is responding to the wireless remotes and it responds to the wireless keypad, however the button doesn't trigger an open/close event.

The button light is ON, and it switches off when the button is depressed, then switches back on when the button is released however the singal doesn't seem to be making it to the opener.  It is on warranty, so I called and they sent me a new button, however I am not sure thats the problem.

I tried shorting the red and white wire from the button because thats how I opened the garage door at my last house (the button was smashed, just had two wires hanging on the wall that I touched together), however shorting the wires did nothing.

I am thinking there is probably a bad relay in the opener.  Or maybe the door button for this model does something special?  What are your thoughts?

Model: Chamberlain LW3000

Comment: So it opens and closes with wireless remotes, just not the wired one?

Comment: @Steven Correct... and I should point out that the button itself is rather sophisticated.  It has seperate buttons for the light, and locking the opener as well.  It must be sending different low voltage signals for different commands.  None of the buttons do anything.

Comment: I have a similar pad and I had a problem where none of the openers were working (wired or wireless) - I had to reset the unit as well as perform a key sequence on the opener (don't remember what it was) to re-pair it

Comment: The downloadable instructions show a different, probably older wiring connection scheme, indicating these are newly implemented components. The chance of a defective component is increased significantly in my eyes. If the button replacement doesn't pan out, the main control board is my next suspect, not a relay, since the remotes seem to operate them fine. The wired and unwired control segments are the uncommon denominator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the new button in the mail from the warranty claim that I made.  I replaced the button and the door works perfectly now.

Thanks for your help and advice.